# I can not copy database MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I created a mongo cluster in ubuntu and run the copy in the sharding with a small database, everything works fine.

The problem is that when I try to copy a database 300gb, is not getting done. The host where I have the mongos instance, run the following:

```
db.runCommand ({copydb: 1, fromdb: "tranches" todb: "tranches" fromhost: "mongoserver: 27025"})
```

And the following appears:

```
{ "code": 13398,"ok": 0,"errmsg": "exception: cant copy to sharded DB" }
```

What could be the problem ?, any idea for the problem?.

Comment: It seems like the code says copydb is not supported for sharded databases.  See https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/s/commands_public.cpp#L800

Comment: Perhaps you should try MangoDB.  Pretty sure it supports everything you need.

Comment: Yeah its clear on that post and i think it has to do with the global locking on a distributed environment. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/copydb/  
1)Do not use copydb from a mongos instance.
2)Do not use copydb to copy databases that contain sharded collections.

Comment: ok thank you very much for your comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The copydb command cannot be run against a database in which sharding has been enabled.

In this situation I would recommend using the [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) and [mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) tools to extract your collection data and to restore to a different collection / database / cluster. These tools can be run against mongos and will respect shard boundaries.